# openpyxl error Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

First of all I'm a rookie in programming.

I'm trying to export MySQL database to excel format with python3. I'm using openpyxl for it. Now I have a interesting error in excel. If I run the code but the SQL query is small (around 1000 rows) then I do not have an error when opeening the excel, but if it is bigger (>30k rows) when I try to open the excel I have an error:

error135840_01.xmlErrors were detected in file 'C:\Users\id022504\PycharmProjects\GetMySQLdata\Interface planning _mau.xlsx'Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Interesting enough when I use Open XML SDK to open the excel file it points that the issue is in the color:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2keM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQIUc.png)

Bellow is the code:

```
import mysql.connector
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, Font, Alignment
import datetime
import os
from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="10.10.10.10",
  user="user",
  passwd="password"
)

#Funcao para por as colunas com auto size
def auto_column_resize(worksheet):
    for col in worksheet.columns:
         max_length = 0
         column = col[0].column # Get the column name
         for cell in col:
             try: # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
                 if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                     max_length = len(cell.value)
             except:
                 pass
         adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
         if adjusted_width <= 95:
            worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
         else:
             worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width =95
    return worksheet

# definir path
path='C:/Users/'

# definir path para arquivo
path_arquivo='C:/Users/Arquivo/'

#definir tamanho do arquivo
arquivo_file_size = 26





# Abrir ficheiro actual e guardar nos arquivos
current_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path+"Interface planning.xlsx")
current_ws = current_wb["Ports allocation"]


if int(datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]) >9:
    current_wb.save("{0}/Interface planning_{1}{2}.xlsx".format(path_arquivo, str(int(datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[0])),str(int(datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]))))
else:
    #introduce 0 in the week so it can calculate later which file is the oldest
    current_wb.save("{0}/Interface planning_{1}0{2}.xlsx".format(path_arquivo, str(int(datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[0])),str(int(datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]))))

#Abrir SQL e comando
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT hostname, hardware, port_label, ifHighSpeed, ifAdminStatus, ifOperStatus, ifAlias FROM `observium`.`ports` JOIN `observium`.`devices` ON `observium`.`devices`.device_id = `observium`.`ports`.device_id WHERE (port_label LIKE 'xe-%' or port_label LIKE 'et-%' or port_label LIKE 'ge-%' or port_label LIKE '%Ethernet%') and port_label NOT RLIKE '[.][1-9]' ORDER BY hostname, port_label;")


#Meter em tupel os dados recebidos pela base de dados
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
header = mycursor.column_names

#Criar workbook
new_wb = Workbook()

#Criar worksheet
new_ws = new_wb.active
new_ws.title = "Ports allocation"

############################################## Meter dados SQL em excel ##########################################

#Add header information and formating
new_ws.append(header)

new_ws["H1"].value = "Person assigned"

for format_row in new_ws:
    for i in range(8):
        format_row[i].font = Font(bold=True)

#Add content from SQL to excel
for row in myresult:
    new_ws.append(row)

new_ws.auto_filter.ref = "A:H"

#Verificar o estado da interface e colocar a pessoa responsavel se a interface esta administrativamente e operacionalmente em baixo
for current_ws_row in current_ws:
    if current_ws_row[7].value is not None:
        for new_ws_row in new_ws:
            if (new_ws_row[4].value != "up" or new_ws_row[5].value != "up") and current_ws_row[0].value == new_ws_row[0].value and current_ws_row[2].value == new_ws_row[2].value :
                new_ws_row[7].value= current_ws_row[7].value
                new_ws_row[6].value = current_ws_row[6].value


for format_row in new_ws:
    for i in range(8):
        format_row[i].border = Border(right=Side(style='thin'),)

#Meter o worksheet bonitinho
new_ws = auto_column_resize(new_ws)
new_ws.sheet_view.zoomScale = 85
c=new_ws['D2']
new_ws.freeze_panes = c

wrap_alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
for row in new_ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell.alignment = Alignment(shrink_to_fit=True)

#Salvar workbook
new_wb.save(path+"Interface planning.xlsx")

#remover ficheiro no arquivo

count_files=0
#infinite time
file_to_delete = '299952'

for directory in os.walk(path_arquivo):
    for file in directory[2]:
        count_files = count_files+1
        if  str(file)[-11:-5] < file_to_delete:
            file_to_delete = str(file)[-11:-5]


if count_files > arquivo_file_size:
    os.remove(path_arquivo+'Interface planning_'+file_to_delete+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error from Excel has nothing to do with the SDK's warning which refers to styles and is erroneous because the child elements of font can be in any order. Please provide some source code.

Comment: Post the source code. We can't reproduce your problem without it.

Comment: Thank you guys for the initiative, I have edit the post and put the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue, in one of the cells there was the "=" symbol and somehow excel identify it as a formula. To solve the issue I just clean up the "=".

```
import re
try:
    new_ws_row[7].value = re.sub("=", "", new_ws_row[7].value)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I think if the cell starts with the "=" sign, then this issue happens. Instead of removing all equal signs, it will be good to remove just the ones at the beginning. `new_ws_row[7].value = re.sub('^=+', '', new_ws_row[7].value)`

Comment: Or add a space before the = and Excel will properly treat it as text.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the awesome answer provided by Pedro on 12th December 2018.

I found below to be an efficient way to address trouble columns containing values starting with an equal sign when trying to use Openpyxl

```
for cell in ws['R']:
if "=" in str(cell.value):
     cell.value = re.sub('^=', ' =', cell.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a length limit of 255 chars in Excel formulas. Keep an eye on that.